# PDF Certification signature: View initial revision

Tags: pdf, digital-signature

I have a pdf document with multiple signature fields. The first field is signed with a certification signature. Whenever an approval signature is added to my document, a new revision is created and it is possible to view this specific revision in acrobat.

Is it also possible to view the original/initial version of the document? I cannot find this option in acrobat reader.

[image]

Edit: @mkl showed me the solution. I didn't find this option before, because I always used a rather old [sample pdf](https://blogs.adobe.com/security/files/2012/03/SampleForm_CDS_RE.pdf) from adobe (see screenshot).

[image]

For some reason the 'View signed version' option is not available there

Comment: You can also retrieve the revision created for the certification signature in Adobe Reader, just like those created for approval signatures.

Comment: Your question is about general computing hardware and software - this question is more likely to get an answer on Super User and is not appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: @mkl: I added a screenshot of a sample pdf. For Revision 2 there is a 'View changes in this revision' link, but for the initial version it is missing.

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche I guess you are right. I'm used to use stackoverflow...

Comment: It's not because you're used to using a hammer, that everything is a nail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [For] an approval signature [...] it is possible to view this specific revision in acrobat.
>
> Is it also possible to view the original/initial version of the document? I cannot find this option in acrobat reader.

In your screen shot you show that the option to view the signed revision is immediately accessible from the signature panel for approval signatures but not for certification signatures.

If you right-click a signature there, though, to get its context menu, you'll find that option there for certification signatures, too:

[image: screen shot]

PS: In English speaking forums it may be better to switch the language of a program to English before making a screen shot.

---

In a comment you say about that option that

> for the sample doc I always used for evaluating, it is not available (see my edit). Do you have any idea what's different?

Your example file is not a "normal" PDF, it merely serves as a container for transporting a XFA form definition. (These piggyback XFA definitions have been deprecated in ISO 32000-2.)

When Adobe Reader (or an other XFA aware PDF viewer; there are not many) displays such a PDF, it ignores regular PDF contents completely and instead draws a form based on the attached XFA XML file.

Apparently Adobe's signature panel does not support the same features for such XFA PDFs as it does for "normal" PDFs.

Comment: Thank you! This actually works for documents created by myself. But for the sample doc I always used for evaluating, it is not available (see my edit). Do you have any idea what's different?

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!